# Tensorflow - Does TF object detection API train.py support difficult flag from PASCAL VOC

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, flags, training-data

Hey guys another day another question, so my colleageus and I were wondering if the train.py and trainer.py from the object detection API uses or evaluates the difficult or truncated flag from our PASCAL VOC files which can be stuffed into the tfrecords.

I haven't seen it directly in the code, but my python skills are like a newbie. So maybe someone can give me a hint.

Thanks and regards